# Select with "Ratio_to_report" on table

Tags: sql, postgresql

i want to select the ration of the total price or the id_programme made by id_lot :
here is the table :

```
 id_lot | id_programme | surface | prix 
--------+--------------+---------+------
    101 |            1 |      30 |  180
    201 |            1 |      30 |  185
    391 |            2 |      40 |  145
```

i have try this :

```
     select id_lot,id_programme ,                                                    
     ratio_to_report(sum(prix)) over(partition by id_programme) as 
     ratio
     from t
     group by id_lot,id_programme;;
```

and i get this error :

> select id_lot,id_programme ,ratio_to_report(sum(prix)) over(...
>                                       ^
>   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Your code works when I try it:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=96a00e8bef9f202fb7dd4d7ee0792cc1.  Your error does not look like an Oracle error.  Are you sure you are using Oracle?

Comment: The error message looks more like Postgres. Are you using Postgres and not Oracle?

Comment: i am  using psql

Comment: @SaraStone . . . This can be confusing.  "psql" is the interactive interface to Postgres.  "plsql" is the scripting language for Oracle.  "pgsql" or "plpgsql" is the scripting language for Postgres.  I fixed your tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly do the calculation for `ratio_to_report()`.  Does this work?

```
select id_lot, id_programme,  
       sum(prix) / sum(sum(prix)) over (partition by id_programme) as ratio
from t
group by id_lot, id_programme;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ed4dda9e496600f6bff4db596ef6f40b) is a db<>fiddle using Postgres.

Comment: that's right ! and working too  thank you , so if i get it , the ratio_to_report is on Oracle and iw as on postgres sql , my bad sorry !